# Can you find the shape of a a potential well based on a given eigenfunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The time-independent Schrödinger equation can be solved to find the eigenfunctions for a particle of a given mass in a given potential well. Can this process be reversed? Can algorithms that are used to find eigenfunctions based on potential wells be flipped to do this?

Comment: If you also have the eigenvalues, then, at least in the finite dimensional case, I would say you are good to go

Comment: I thought eigenvalues were a given with the eigenfunction. And just so we're clear, eigenvalue refers to the energy of the particle in this case, right?

Comment: yap, I mean, I could hypothetically only know eigenvectors and not eigenvalues, but yea usually they como together